# proof of the product: x times m derivative of delta function.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, distribution-theory, quantum-mechanics

The question is in  one dimension and is : Prove that $$x\delta^{(m)}=-m\delta^{(m-1)},\ m \in \mathbb{N},$$
where $\delta^{(m)}$ is the $m$-derivative of $\delta.$

As I know, I got through this way:
$$\langle x\delta^{(m)},\psi \rangle=\langle\delta^{(m)},x\psi\rangle$$
$$ -\langle\delta^{(m-1)},\frac{d(x\psi)}{dx}\rangle=-\langle\delta^{(m-1)},x\psi'+\psi\rangle$$
$$= -\langle \delta^{(m-1)},\psi\rangle -\langle \delta^{(m-1)},x\psi'\rangle=-\delta^{(m-1)}  -\langle \delta^{(m-1)},x\psi'\rangle$$

I can get away with developing the term with $(\psi)',$ but then the $(m-1)$- derivative would disappear, any hints?

I thought about the possibility of error in writing the book, I don´t know.

Comment: I don't see how you got from $\langle x \delta^{(m)}, \psi \rangle = \langle \delta^{(m)}, x \psi \rangle$ to the next line.

Comment: The product of a distribution T by a function f is $$\langle  Tf,\psi\rangle=\langle T,f\psi\rangle$$  The derivative of a distribution  T is defined by  $$\langle \frac{d^n T}{dx^n}, \psi \rangle = (-1)^n \langle T , \frac{d^n \psi}{dx^n} \rangle$$ as i down m by one, i used derivative one time

Comment: I think I found a way to move forward, if it works I will update with this answer

Comment: Oh right, you just meant all four expressions are equal. I was thrown off by the lack of an $=$ between them.

Comment: yeah, i forgot this equal hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for any test function $\psi\in \mathcal D(\mathbb R)$ :
\begin{align}
\langle x\delta^{(m)},\psi\rangle &= \langle \delta^{(m)},x\psi\rangle\\
&= (-1)^m \langle \delta, (x\psi)^{(m)}\rangle 
\end{align}

Now, using the Leibniz formula, we have :
$$(x\psi)^{(m)} = \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}x^{(k)}\psi^{(m-k)} = x\psi^{(m)} + m\psi^{(m-1)}$$
Therefore :
\begin{align}
\langle x\delta^{(m)},\psi\rangle &= (-1)^m\langle \delta, x\psi^{(m)} + m\psi^{(m-1)}\rangle \\
&= (-1)^m\langle \delta,  m\psi^{(m-1)}\rangle \\
&= \langle - m\delta^{(m-1)},\psi\rangle
\end{align}
i.e. $x \delta^{(m)} = -m\delta^{(m-1)}$.

*Remark* :
You can also prove this by induction without using test functions. This is true for $m = 0$ and if $m>0$ and the formula is true for $m-1$ :
$$x\delta^{(m)} = \left(x\delta^{(m-1)}\right)' - \delta^{(m-1)} = \left(-(m-1)\delta^{(m-2)}\right)' - \delta^{(m-1)} = -m\delta^{(m-1)}$$

Comment: I didn't know this version of Leibniz's rule, and I was getting to this result doing the derivatives one by one and I was thinking about how to induce to m-1 times, but it was taking a lot of work, Leibniz's rule is perfect, thank you very much.